# Which function can be used to select an item in a tree view with Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, treeview, treemodel

Which function can be used to select an item in a tree view (or model) with Qt? I even don't know the function is in tree view or model. How to do it? Any function like select(const QModelIndex & index)? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QTreeView deals in QModelIndexes. You can control selections through the selectionModel on the view:
http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qabstractitemview.html#selectionModel